# Gunicorn CPU usage increasing to a very high value

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

We are using Gunicorn with Nginx. After every time we restart gunicorn, the CPU usage took by Gunicorn keeps on increasing gradually. This increases from 0.5% to around 85% in a matter of 3-4 days. On restarting gunicorn, it comes down to 0.5%.
Please suggest what can cause this issue and how to go forward to debug and fix this.

Answer (score 4):

- Check workers configuration. Try use the following: `cores * 2 -1`
- Check your application, seems that your application is blocking / freezing threads. Add timeout to all api calls, database queries, etc.
- You can add an APM software to analyze your application, for example datadog.